# How to display a message entered in fragment1 to fragment2?

Tags: android

Fragment1 has a button and edittext, fragment2 has textview.

Now i want to display the text entered in fragment1 to the fragment2 textview, can anyone help how to do this?

Comment: Please post some of your code, it depends on how are your Fragments organized, if they are both on the screen, and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can send your text to fragment 2 using a static method like this:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(final String text) {
final MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
final Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
args.putString("my_text", name);
myFragment.setArguments(args);
return myFragment;
}
```

and then after creating the fragment you can get text inside it like this:

`String text = getArguments().getString("my_text");`